# How present an arrays attribute with Knockout

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I want to use an observableArray as the default tags in a select2 plugin, but I´m struggling with getting the plug-in to show my arrays Name attribute.

The html goes like this:

```
<div data-bind="with: SelectedText">
    <h1>Title: <span data-bind="text: Title"></span></h1>
    <div>
        <label>A: Local Managers:</label>
        <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: managerTags, select2: { tags: $root.Tags, minimumInputLength: 1, tokenSeparators: [',', ' '] }">        
        Local  Selected: <span data-bind="text: managerTags"></span>
        <label>B: Global Managers:</label>
        <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: $root.managerTags, select2: { tags: $root.promans, minimumInputLength: 1, tokenSeparators: [',', ' '] }"> 
        D: Global Selected: <span data-bind="text: $root.managerTags"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have 2 issues here: One is why $root.Tags isn´t displayed as the preset tags while $root.promans is.
The second is how I can get the "Name" attribute of the managerTags object collection to show in my input (and the ) in "A: Local Managers" as it does with "B: Global Managers".

I understand I most probably will have to do something with my ViewModel, but I´m not capable of seeing how it should be to get the data right in the view.

Full fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6cWDX/2/

Answer (score 1):

When you are passing `$root.Tags`, you are passing an observableArray that contains objects with observables.  The `select2` plugin doesn't know how to unwrap the observables.  You could choose to do some unwrapping in the binding or if you were to pass in `ko.toJS($root.Tags)` it would recursively unwrap all of the tags and return a plain JavaScript array with plain objects (no observables).

The other issue is that the `value` binding is going against `$root.selectedText().managerTags` (could just be `managerTags` since you are within a `with` for `selectedText` already) which is a computed. This computed does not have a `write` function, so the `value` binding is not able to write back against it. You might want to use observables for those fields and populate them initially based on the type of the `TextTags`.

You could use a [writeable computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#writeable_computed_observables) where you would have to take the new value and reconcile it with the values in `TextTags`.

Comment: Thanks, Ryan! :) You are (of course ;) spot on! 
Being a rather novice with knockout (and javascript) I feel Writeable computed observables is a step up… ;)

Comment: I guess the "read" is only a return of the observable itself (?) while in the "write"-part I have to do something like loop over the input params and do a self.Tags.push( new Tag( param ))?